# Darken an opaque UIView without blending

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uikit, opacity, alphablending

My App's background is an opaque `UIImageView`. Under some circumstances I would like to darken this down in an animated way from full brightness to about 50%. Currently I lower the alpha property of the view and this works well. Because nothing is behind the view, the background image just becomes dark.

However, I've been profiling using the Core Animation Instrument and when I do this, I see that **the whole background shows as being blended**. I'd like to avoid this if possible.

It seems to me that this would be achievable during compositing. If a view is opaque, it is possible to mix is with black without anything behind showing through. It's not necessary to blend it, just adjust the pixel values.

I wondered if this was something that UIKit's GPU compositing supports. While blending isn't great, it's probably a lot better than updating the image on the CPU, so I think a CPU approach is probably not a good substitute.

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13970373/2547229) asks about this, and a few ideas are suggested including setting the Alpha. No one has brought up a mechanism for avoiding blending though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important question here is whether you want the change to using a darkened background to be animated.

## Not animated

Prepare two different background images and simply swap between them. The [`UIImage+imageEffects`](https://github.com/iGriever/TWSReleaseNotesView/blob/master/TWSReleaseNotesView/UIImage%2BImageEffects.h) library could help with generating the darkened image, or give you some leads.

## Animated.

Take a look at [**GPUImage**](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) - "An open source iOS framework for GPU-based image and video processing". Based on this you could render the background in to the scene in a darkened way.

Comment: Animated. I should have mentioned that, so I've edited the question, thanks for prompting me to clarify. I don't see how the linked library helps?

Comment: I had a look at the implementation code, thanks. I also should have made it clearer in the question that I want to keep this all on the GPU. I've amended it.

Comment: @Benjohn, in this case, take a look at this framework - "An open source iOS framework for GPU-based image and video processing".  
https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Comment: Cool – that looks like a useful reference. I was wondering if I could just use some GLSlang to define how the background is put together and then I'd be able to do the whole thing in a single pass and avoid lots of compositing (it's more involved than I hinted at). I think this is the right answer, and I think I'll leave it for version 1.1 :-)

Comment: @Benjohn, good! I've updated my answer. Please, mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks for the edit – I've done a further to structure it making the animated / not-animated difference clear. I'm going to leave the question open for a while as I've got a hope someone will step up and say, "oh, you need the … parameter on `UIView`". Thanks.